# C read call buffering extra character

Tags: c, sockets, file-io

I am trying to read a file and send it over the network:
below is my code at server for file reading and sending,

```
while((sent = read(fp, send_buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
{
    write(cssock, send_buf, strlen(send_buf));
    memset(send_buf, 0, BUFSIZE);
}
```

and I am reading it at client as:

```
while(readBytes = read(sock, file_data, BUFSIZE) > 0)
{
        write(fp, file_data, strlen(file_data));
}
```

file is transferred fine but I am getting an extra character at the end of buffer and my file is written as:

> hello my name is abcd garbage-char

garbage-char is some arbitery character. Any idea why would I get such extra character?

note: I have double checked my file and it has nothing but the string "my name is abcd". No space, no new line. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which extra character  do you get ?

Comment: its a byte extra. I am unable to paste it here. A square with like below:
77
0F

Comment: I suggest you print your send_buf in your server and your file_data in the client see whether they are same. And also a suggestion, use memset(send_buf, 0, BUFSIZE) before you read your file in server, and  memset(filedata, 0, BUFSIZE) before you read from socket in client.

Comment: `write(cssock, send_buf, strlen(send_buf) + 1);`  Send the NULL byte

Comment: Thanks yanchong. I had done memset at my server but missed it at client. Can you post this as answer? I'll mark it.

Comment: if you use calloc the memory will be memset to 0 automatically

Comment: OK, I have posted this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual cause of the problem was the `POSIX read()` API. It does not return a NULL terminated string which was stuffing garbage characters in the buffer.

What I did to solve this problem is below:

```
while((sent = read(fp, send_buf, BUFSIZE - 1)) > 0)
{
    if(sent < BUFSIZE)
       send_buf[sent] = '\0';
    else
       send_buf[BUFSIZE] = '\0';

    write(cssock, send_buf, strlen(send_buf));
    memset(send_buf, 0, BUFSIZE);
}
```

and it solved it. Thank you all for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here is simple. Use the length of the data you received, not the length of the string. You did not receive a "string". You received an arbitrary block of bytes which can be any value from 0 to 255. So `strlen` may return useless results. But the number of bytes read is always accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you print your send_buf in your server and your file_data in the client see whether they are same. And also a suggestion, use memset(send_buf, 0, BUFSIZE) before you read your file in server, and memset(filedata, 0, BUFSIZE) before you read from socket in client.

Comment: It works for a small file but for large file it is still giving problem of garbage characters. I have solved it and will post as an answer.